# How to run python setup.py develop command inside virtualenv using ansible

Tags: python, setup.py, ansible

I want to execute `python setup.py develop` command inside of virtualenv using ansible.
How to do it?

Probably could be something like this:

```
- name: egg
  shell: "python setup.py develop"
```

But I need to execute it inside of virtualenv. How can I do it?

Answer (score 9):

One way is to call python from the virtualenv's bin directory.

```
- name: egg
  shell: "/path/to/env/bin/python setup.py develop"
```

Answer (score 6):

I simply use the `pip -e` approach, through  the [pip command](http://docs.ansible.com/pip_module.html) (that guarantees that a `virtualenv` exists), adding  the `-e` parameter with `extra_args`. Eg:

```yaml
    - name: install MYPACKAGE in VIRTUALENV    
      pip: name='PATH TO MYPACKAGE'
           extra_args='-e'   # this creates a link rather then copying the files
           virtualenv='PATH OF YOUR VIRTUALENV'  # will be created if does not exist
```

Optionally you might want to specify how the `virtualenv` script is executed, eg. if you need `python3` add:

```yaml
           virtualenv_command='python3 /PATH_TO_VENV/virtualenv.py'
```

UPDATE as of ansible.builtin 2.0, there's now an opt-in `editable` parameter:

```yaml
    - name: install MYPACKAGE in VIRTUALENV    
      pip:
        name: 'PATH TO MYPACKAGE'
        editable: true
        virtualenv: 'PATH TO YOUR VIRTUALENV'  # will be created if does not exist
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also try chaining commands together.

```
- name: chained shell command
  shell: "source /path/to/env/bin/activate; python setup.py develop"
```